# Is there a way I can turn a KVP dictionary into a String?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to turn my `[String:Bool]` variable that I fetched from FireStore into a string.

Example:

```
var action = ["Nourishing":true, "Radiance":true]
```

to:

> "Nourishing, Radiance"

Is this possible?

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you want all of the keys or just keys that have a value of `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want all of the keys combined into a string you can do:

```
var action = ["Nourishing":true, "Radiance":true, "Whatever":false]
let keysAll = action.keys.joined(separator: ", ")
print(keysAll)
```

Result:

> Nourishing, Radiance, Whatever

If you only want certain keys then you first need to filter the key/values as needed. For example, if you only want keys where the value is `true`, you can do:

```
var action = ["Nourishing":true, "Radiance":true, "Whatever":false]
let keysTrue = action.filter { $0.value }.keys.joined(separator: ", ")
print(keysTrue)
```

Result:

> Nourishing, Radiance

Or alternatively you can do:

```
var action = ["Nourishing":true, "Radiance":true, "Whatever":false]
let keysTrue = action.flatMap { $0.value ? $0.key : nil }.joined(separator: ", ")
print(keysTrue)
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

Also there is harder solution by using reduce

```
 let action = ["Nourishing":true, "Radiance":true] 

     let  data =   action.reduce("") { (result, dic) -> String in
            return result.count == 0  ? (result + "\(dic.key)") :  (result + ",\(dic.key)")
      }
     print(data)
```